# LINQ stack overflow selecting many

Tags: c#, linq, sqlite, ado.net

I have a scenario where I have a table of "batch" and a table of "test" where "test" contains an FK to "batch" and a many tests can belong to a batch.

I want to be able to select multiple batches and find all tests that belong to them. I do this by producing a list of PKs to the batches I'm interested in and then the following LINQ query:

```
var ret =
from t in tests 
from b in indices //indices is a list of long PK's belonging to selected batches
where t.batch_id == b
select t;
```

It works but when my selection size exceeds 14 batches, I get a "SQLite error
parser stack overflow" on the LINQ expression regardless of how many tests are found.

I want to be able to handle large selections if possible. How can I do this?

Comment: Somebody tagged this as LinqToSql.  Can you confirm?  If not - please edit the tags.  Also - since you're getting a Sqlite error, would you mind posting the sql that was sent to the database? (Use DataContext.Log = Console.Out, if you're using linq to sql.

Comment: LINQ to SQL does not work with SQLite.

Comment: Most likely using LINQ to ADO.NET using SQLite ADO.net provider.  The linq-to-sql tag has been removed and added sqlite and ado.net.

Comment: can you provide what version of SQLite you are using and if this is .Net or Mono based calls?  Did you compile your own version of SQLite or download a pre-compiled version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The LINQ provider may be blowing up because it's trying to issue 1 query per index. You can verify this (if SQL is in fact getting generated at all) by profiling the DB and seeing if it's actually issuing 1 query per index.

Try this instead:

```
var ret =
from t in tests 
where indices.Contains(t.batch_id)
select t;
```

Answer (score 1):

If JeffN825's query doesn't resolve your issue, which I would give high odds on it doing so, you may need to compile your own SQLite and set the -DYYSTACKDEPTH value to something bigger than the default.  So you will need to find out what it was set to and then maybe double it and go from there.  The full line you would pass is `CFLAGS="-DYYSTACKDEPTH=1000"` changing the 1000 to be what how deep you want the stack to be.